# how can I store images images like thumbshots or shrinkthe web does?

Tags: image, image-processing, uiimageview

I have more than 500k images in single directory. actually this is windows hence I cant explore it normally. I want send send these respective images on to a web page on call. so for that how do I store images in large sacel and how can I call them??

Comment: Can you please explain your problem in a more concise manner?

Comment: You are uploading half a million images to a webapp?  Or did I misread you?

Comment: It is not a problem actually I am looking for a solution. if you look at thumbshots they serve millions of images to web pages on api call.if I normally link these images to a webpage on directory wise I believe the loading time is very high, so kind of storage solutions or API call or something which can deliver image faster

Comment: So do you have these images stored offline or online? I guess this hasn't come out yet. And you have a webapp which is running on some server? Or do you simply want to create small thumbnails from the large images in that folder? If the latter, have a look ad libgd or imagemagick on the server to scale the images down...

Answer (score 1):

Sounds adventurous... But it's probably best that you resize all of your images first and turn them into thumbnails. You can do batch resizing using ImageMagick command line tools on your local machine where you've got all your pics.

You can download it here [Link](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows)

Here's an article on how to batch resize all images within a directory:

http://blog.coppermine-gallery.net/2009/07/08/batch-resize-using-imagemagick/

All the best